# RoR and Relational databases: handling Model default values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, relational-database

I'm working on a RoR project for work, and I'm having trouble deciding about the design of my relational database tables.

Consider the following:

I've got a model Product, each product has a unique name.

I've also got a model called Shop, each shop has many products.

Finally, I have an Order model, Order is obviously connected to the shop which the order has been made from, and to the list of products which were ordered.

I would like to keep default values (e.g. default price) for each product, and I'd like each Shop to be able to overwrite those default values if needed, but can't really decide on the strategy of doing so.

What I have in mind is as follows:

- Create a Product table, which will include the product name, and also, columns to keep the product's default values (e.g. price)
- Create a Shop table, which will include everything which has to do with the shop.
- Create a Product_To_Shop table, which will hold the product quantity for that exact shop, and will hold additional columns, which match the Product default values columns which will let the shop overwrite the default product related values.

Now when I'd like to get the price for a specific order, i'll first check out the Product_To_Shop table, for the related Product and Shop, and check the Price field for the matching row, and in case it's not set to a value (nil), head to the Product table and fetch the default price value for the relevant product.

The whole thing looks a bit complex for a task which seems a bit more trivial.

I was wondering if anyone ever had to deal with keeping default values in the database like that and has a more elegant solution, since this one seems like an overkill...

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

1. Create a Products table, which will include the products data ( but no prices).
2. Create a Shops table, which will include the shops data.
3. Create a Prices table, which will include Product_id, Shop_id, Price.

Shop_id defaulted to null which will indicate your default price

When you need the price get the one matching shop_id or isnull